# Mock with sinon injection services in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, sinon

I have the following class in a parent project (parent project will be a module in child project):

```
export default class testService {

    constructor({loggerFactory,childService}) {
        this.logger = loggerFactory.logger
        this.child = childService;
    }
}
```

when I run test the test has been failed because the childservice does not exist. 
the service is exist only if I open the child project that includes the parent module in the node modules

so my question is how can i mock that to prevent failure in test

Answer (score 2):

You can pass in a stub `childService` when instantiating the class in your test:

```js
const loggerFactory = {
  logger: () => {},
}

const childService = {}

const mockTestService = new testService({loggerFactory, childService});
```